# Loading a script file in a Chrome App Sandbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome App, and I have a script file that's saved in the app's sandboxed filesystem. (It's available via a URL `filesystem:chrome-extension_****/Persistent/script.js`

I'm able to use Chrome's FileSystemAPI to read the file in the main app window. However, I need it to be accessible and executable in a sandboxed page.

I have the following in my manifest -

```
"sandbox": {
      "pages": ["sandboxed_page.html"],
      "content_security_policy": "sandbox allow-scripts;"
},
```

And I'm using the page like this:

`<iframe id="sandbox_frame" seamless="seamless" src="sandboxed_page.html"  sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>`

I tried loading the file in the main app window, use `window.URL.createObjectURL()` to convert it to a blob: URL, and passed this URL via `postMessage()` to the sandbox. In the sandbox, I'm trying to load the URL into a `<script>` element. I get an error saying `Not allowed to load local resource: blob:chrome-extension%3A//...`

The other option (which is working) is load the contents of script.js in the main app, and send the entire string through postMessage(). Not sure this is a good idea, as script.js could get pretty big.

Am I doing something wrong, or is loading local scripts in sandboxes prohibited by Chrome's security policies?

I went through https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external, but there's no mention of sending the external resources to the sandbox.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've set an alternate script-src in the sandbox CSP, so I think you can just load it via <script src="script.js"> like in the main window?

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxed pages execute in a unique origin i.e. one that is different from the App itself, and you can't access filesystem URLs across different origins. The same goes for object URLs created from those files.

You're basically stuck with the postMessage approach, though you may be able to make it more efficient by transfering it as an ArrayBuffer rather than copying the data as a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Passing_data_by_transferring_ownership_(transferable_objects).